# SesionState Timeout not working in my project?

Tags: asp.net

I am working on  a web application based project in this application i want if a user `remains idle for continuous 10 minutes` then he will automatically `logged out` from the application.
for this i have tried this code in the web.config but this isn't working.

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="2"></sessionState>
```

Suggest me some other possible way how can i do this in my application?

Comment: What is the authentication mode you are using?

Comment: How do you expect to see the "logout"? The user is not going to be redirected automatically to a login page. Also: authentication and session may use different timeouts.

Comment: Authentication mode is "form". @Bhasyakarulu Kottakota

Comment: I am expecting if user found inactive for 10 minutes he should get looged out and redirect back to login page. @Hans Kesting

Answer (score 1):

Use should set timeout for forms authentication.

Notice that session timeout should be longer: ~  2 * formsTimeout

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login" timeout="2" name=".yourAuthCookieName" />
</authentication>
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="4"></sessionState>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
 <configuration>
 <system.web>
  sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120" />
 </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

and Find here more about setting session timeout in application pool 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771956%28v=ws.10%29.aspx